# Unknown Service Identification

Tags: ports, identification

How can one identify a service running on a non-standard port? I'm not talking about services like webserver or FTP since nmap can do that without any problems. I'm talking about services that are not *that* common, like Java RMI, X11, ...

What I found till now is amap and the NMAP+V patch and some standard strings like:

- version
- ?
- \r\n\r\n
- help
- ...

Is someone aware of any kind of list/paper for a good start?

Answer (score 2):

nmap+V and amap are old patches and forks of nmap that was used before nmap added version scanning into the core build. Both tools are mostly obsolete now. Even the AMAP [website](http://www.thc.org/thc-amap/) agrees.

```
nmap -sV -V -ip address-
```

The -V flag increases the verbosity of nmap's output, giving you the exact header information that nmap uses to determine what service/version is running on the port.

In the case of non-standard programs, your best bet would be to use Google to search for more information about a particular header or other information that nmap returns. There is really too many obscure programs for anyone to provide a comprehensive list in one place.

Comment: Well to identify a non-standard program I have to get a header first - I need to send something to the service in otder to (hopefully) get an error message, which I can google afterward. But still, I need to start somwhere and that's the reason for my question. I thought maybe someone saw something useful somewhere ;)

Comment: @i-- The -V flag allows to to observe the packets returned by the service in response to nmap's -sV scan. One -V flag might not be enough - i can't remember at this point. Try adding another -V if one doesn't return the necessary information.

Comment: You could also fire up Wireshark and analyse the packets yourself, during an nmap scan.